# Why is it not validating recaptcha in my code

Tags: python, html, flask, web-applications, recaptcha

I am building a register page using flask. I wanted to implement flask recaptch. It's not throwing any error on the console but when I click on register after filling all the credentials, it's not stored in the table and does not go to login page.

I am trying the reCAPTCHA thing for the first time. I have implemented all the config for the reCAPTCHA. And the keys are for reCAPTCHA v2.

Here is the code for the Flask App

```
    app.config['RECAPTCHA_USE_SSL'] = False
    app.config['RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY'] = PUBLIC_KEY
    app.config['RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY'] = PRIVATE_KEY
    app.config['RECAPTCHA_OPTIONS'] = {'theme': 'black'}

    class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
        username = StringField(validators=[
            validators.InputRequired(), validators.Length(min=4, max=20)], render_kw= {"placeholder": "Username"})

        email = StringField(validators=[
            validators.InputRequired(), validators.Email()], render_kw={"placeholder": "Email"})

        password = PasswordField(validators=[
            validators.InputRequired(), validators.Length(min=8, max=20)], render_kw={"placeholder": "Password"})

        confirm_password = PasswordField(validators=[
            validators.InputRequired(), validators.EqualTo('password', message='Passwords must match')],
            render_kw={"placeholder": "Confirm Password"})

        recaptcha = RecaptchaField()

        submit = SubmitField('Register')


    def validate_username(self, username):
        existing_user_username = User.query.filter_by(
            username=username.data).first()
        if existing_user_username:
            raise ValidationError(
                'That username already exists. Please choose a different one.')

    def validate_password(self, password):
        # Check password strength using zxcvbn
        result = zxcvbn(password.data)

        if result['score'] < 3:
            raise ValidationError(result['feedback']['suggestions'][0])

    def validate_confirm_password(self, field):
        if field.data != self.password.data:
            raise ValidationError('Passwords must match.')

    def validate_recaptcha(self, field):
        if not field.data:
            raise ValidationError('Recaptcha is required. Please complete the Recaptcha challenge.')


@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register_page():
    form = RegisterForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print("Form validated successfully")  # this line is for debugging

        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        new_user = User(username=form.username.data, email_address=form.email.data, _password=hashed_password)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()

        flash('Registration successful!', 'success')

        return redirect(url_for('login_page'))

    else:
        return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: Abinash Rijal you posted your private key for the world to see. You should revoke this key ASAP and create a new one. While @adambasha edited it out for you, it's still in the question history and still needs to be changed.